# Why does Visual Studio 2012 Express's auto parallelization reporting feature only work with Win32?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, parallel-processing, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I tried to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express to auto parallelize a "for" loop in Win 32 bit and x64 bit settings. Command line options were set to /O2 /Qpar /Qpar-report:2 to enable optimization, auto parallelization, and reporting of successful and failed "for" loop auto-parallelization. 32 to 64 bit settings were changed via the method used here: ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9yb4317s.aspx ). A 64 bit version of Windows is running on my computer. The sample code I used came from here: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872235.aspx). The code I ran was as follows:

```
int A[1000];
void test() 
{
___#pragma loop(hint_parallel(0))
___for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) 
___{
______A[i] = A[i] + 1;
___}

___for (int i=1000; i<2000; ++i) 
___{
______A[i] = A[i] + 1;
___}
}

int main() 
{
___test();
___return 0;
}
```

Building with Win32, I yield this reporting output:

```
--- Analyzing function: void __cdecl test(void)
d:\myproject\mytest.cpp(4) : loop parallelized
d:\myproject\mytest.cpp(4) : loop not parallelized due to reason '1008'
```

Building with x64, I did not yield any reports of "loop parallelized" or "loop not parallelized".

Why were there no reports? Is it because I only have visual studio 2012 express, but I needed VS 2012 professional? Does this happen to all computers or across all version of VS 2012? How do I fix this problem so that I will have auto-parallelization reporting ( /Qpar-report:2 ) on with a 64 bit Microsoft Visual Studios project?

Comment: Side note: `A` is only declared as having 1000 elements, so the 2nd loop scribbles on unallocated memory and would probably crash a more complicated program.  (Yes, I know this problem is in the original MS docs and have notified them.)

Answer (score 3):

/Qpar-report works well in x64 compilation mode in the retail edition.  Express doesn't use a special build of the compiler.

A possible explanation is that you forgot to also set the /Qpar-report option for your x64 configuration.  These settings are saved per configuration.  Right-click your project, Properties.  Check the combo boxes at the top of the dialog.  Ensure that you've got the proper Configuration and Platform selected.

And make sure you do this for the Release build, the Debug build doesn't parallelize these loops.